# change text dynamically based on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox

using `FormArray` I had bind checkbox on my component, default `label` of checkbox is **select**, when I clicked checbox, `label` will change to **selected** for each of checkbox (supposed to be), I also got `selectAll` button which change value of all checkbox to `true` and change text to **selected**, my problem is :

- when I select only one checkbox, change `label` will also effected other checkbox
- when I had `selectAll` checkbox, all checkbox label will change to **selected**,then if I unselected individual checkbox, it supposed to be change `label` to **select**

this is what I had tried:

**html file**

```
<div *ngIf="isShowResponse">
    <p>Inquiry Response</p>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckboxes()">
        <ng-container formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let summon of formReceivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked"
        (change)="checkedState(summon)">
            {{ summonText }}
           </ng-container>
       </ng-container>
   </form>
<!-- <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre> -->
<button (click)="selectAll()">Select All</button>
</div>
```

**ts file**

```
    checkedState(summon) {
    summon.checked = !summon.checked;
    this.summonText = summon.checked === true ? 'selected' : 'select';
  }

  selectAll() {
    this.formReceivedSummons.controls.map(value => value.get('isChecked').setValue(true));
    return this.summonText = 'selected';
  }
```

and this is my full [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9fxz9?file=src/app/inquiry-response/inquiry-response.component.html), i could use some suggestion and better practice to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div *ngIf="isShowResponse">
    <p>Inquiry Response</p>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckboxes()">
        <ng-container formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let summon of formReceivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked">
  {{ summon.get('isChecked').value ? 'selected' : 'select' }}
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</form>
<!-- <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre> -->
<button (click)="selectAll()">Select All</button>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-43suh3?file=src/app/inquiry-response/inquiry-response.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I've done some changes, you can try this:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="isShowResponse">
<p>Inquiry Response</p>
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckboxes()">
    <ng-container formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let summon of formReceivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="summon.checked" formControlName="isChecked"
    (change)="checkedState(summon)">
       {{ summon.checked === true ? 'selected' : 'select' }}
    </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
</form>
 <!-- <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre> -->
<button (click)="selectAll()">Select All</button>
</div>
```

**In functions:**

```
selectAll() {
 this.formReceivedSummons.controls.map((summon: any) => {
  summon.checked = true;
 });
}
checkedState(summon) {
 summon.checked = !summon.checked;
}
```